# How to make a direct query to the DB in order to get the list of Iteractions by Team

Tags: tfs

Thinking in user stories, my requirement would be:

As a **development department manager**, I want to **get the full list of iterations by team project**, in order to **have a full view of the milestones set for all the teams**.

My initial approach is a query to the database. Which could be a good approach to build this query?

Is there another way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the TfS operational store directly is unsupported and can lead to your system being unsupported. You should use the reporting tools instead.

TFS creates a data warehouse and cube where all the information is stored for reporting purpose's. You can just plug Excel into the data warehouse a query tye data that you need. If you want trend analysis you can also query the cube.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx

If you have team explorer installed you can also retrieve work items from queries to the operational store through the API. Any query that you can get in TFS you can load into excel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675.aspx